# prevent closing of DOS shell window opened via subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to create a program (it will be used on Windows) to compress a list of files with 7-Zip and other stuff.

I use `subprocess` to run the 7-Zip executable with the correct arguments.
`subprocess` opens a DOS shell with the `7z.exe` output; this is good because there is a percentage indicator of file compression and sometimes the process could be very long. My problem is that the user will be able—voluntarily or accidentally—to interrupt the compression task either by

1. clicking on the close button of the DOS window, or
2. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Is it possible to disable any kind of input to the DOS shell opened from `subprocess`?  Alternatively, how can I pass the output of the DOS shell to my program at runtime?  I tried with `process.stdout.read(1024)` and `process.communicate()`, but both read the output when the subprocess ended; not while it was running.

I've used `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `subprocess.call()` so that I may run all 7-Zip tasks at the same time, but if will be helpful to solve my problem, I can change it.

```
for f in self.fileList:
    destination = self.newPath + "\\" + basename(f) + ".7z"
    arglist = [self.sevZipPath, "a", "-mx9", destination, f]
    sp = subprocess.Popen(
        args = arglist,
        cwd = self.newPath,
        shell = False
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a flag in `startupinfo` to hide the window, and set `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to capture the output of the process.

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
sp = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Remember that `STARTUPINFO` is for Windows only.

Comment: unfortunatly this doesn't work in my case because, as far I've understood, all functions i've found to read the stdout wait until the subprocess end. This means all the application freeze until the subprocess end and only  when it end I can print all output togheter.